# How to set default user to root in WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

On my new laptop I've installed Ubuntu from the store. In the legacy version of WSL, i could change the default user to root by using

`lxrun /setdefaultuser root`

Apparently lxrun is only for the legacy version, is there a way to do this in the new WSL that is installed form the store? I looked at wslconfig but it appears that is just used for managing different distros.

Comment: Try adding `.exe` to the end of `lxrun`: `lxrun.exe /setdefaultuser <new_name>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this from cmd.exe or similar:

For Ubuntu:

```
 ubuntu config --default-user <user_name>
```

For openSuse:

```
 opensuse-42 config --default-user <user_name>
```

For SUSE Linux Enterprise Server:

```
 sles-12 config --default-user <user_name>
```

Warning: The names ubuntu, opensuse-42 or sles-12 might get changed by Microsoft at any time.

Comment: 'Ubuntu' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I guess my answer only counts if you use the Ubuntu subsystem. I'll change my answer to reflect that.

Comment: The only subsystem I have installed is Ubuntu, but I get this error still. What is the output of `where ubuntu`?

Comment: Are you using this from within your subsystem? You have to use it in the general windows shell (just cmd.exe) and not within bash.

Comment: Even if I put the full path of the found `ubuntu.exe` and run the command above, it just says `Access Denied`.

Comment: The following worked for me (the trick was to use full path because I'd had to install ubuntu by a means other than the approved App Store route) ... `C:\Users\<username>\Ubuntu\ubuntu config --default-user oli`

Comment: ubuntu2004.exe is the command that worked for me with ubuntu 20.04

Comment: For there's instruction about `Access Denied` or `System can't execute the progress`, using powershell with admin privileges might help.

Comment: For openSUSE Tumbleweed users, in a command prompt, go to `c:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps>` and there you can run `openSUSE-Tumbleweed.exe config --default-user <your linux username>`

Answer (score 4):

The command was slightly different for me, answering from the future, having installed Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL in November 2019.  In Windows' "Power Shell":

```
ubuntu1804 config --default-user <root_or_other_user_name>
```

I learned it from [these](https://askubuntu.com/a/1111036/950487) [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1078640/950487) and associated comments at "Ask Ubuntu".  I'm just posting here in case others searching arrive here first as I did.

The command

```
ubuntu1804.exe /?
```

was also informative, as I learned from this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1266977/837278) at "Super User".

Comment: yes this worked for me with ubuntu 20.04:  `ubuntu2004'